# DirectoryIndex to external site

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there any way to set the DirectoryIndex in Apache so that it directs to an external webpage? For example, anyone visiting mysite.com/somefolder should be redirected to google.com. I know you can just put the redirect in a file specified by the DirectoryIndex in the folder itself, but I was wondering if I could skip that step.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The directoryindex is either

1. the list of default index files (index.html, index.php, default.htm, etc) or
2. what Apache outputs when it can't find one of the above in a folder.

The Apache options for the 2nd type (at least for the versions of Apache I've used) allow you to *customise* the level of detail in the outout, and it could prepend a HEADER file, or append a README file. This is where you might put a redirect, also.

But I don't think there's an option for redirecting associated with the directoryindex, so the index file, or HEADER or README aren't necessary.

I *usually* see questions about redirecting from the .htaccess file, but I've never checked that out.